# MS SQL Query to remove prefixes

Tags: mysql, sql, string, xcode, str-replace

I have below like column values and would like to exclude the characters as well as the hyphen and only return digits. The replace function is not entirely helpful as sometimes the character length is 3 and sometimes its 4, see below as the digit length changes as well.

```
abc-1234567
sdfr-9876540
try-12345678
case-098765
```

Comment: The title says ms sql, but you tagged the question is mysql. Which one do you use?

Answer (score 2):

If you want the part after the last hyphen, you can use `substring_index()`:

```
select substring_index(col, '-', -1)
```

You can also extract the digits at the end using `regexp_substr()`:

```
select regexp_substr(col, '[0-9]+$')
```